Why Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS doesn't install complete? (failed installation)
I have been using Ubuntu OS for a long time. I recently decided to install Ubuntu  24.04, but I encountered many problems and errors that made me unable to use it. First I got a purple screen with the Ubuntu logo, then I got a red text error, and after installing the OS I got a page that said: Something went wrong! Unfortunately I could not determine exactly where the problem is by looking at the console.
console log:
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Preconfiguring packages ...  
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: E: Can not write log (Is /dev/pts mounted?) - posix_openpt (19: No such device)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Selecting previously unselected package grub2-common.
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: (Reading database ... 120210 files and directories currently installed.)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Preparing to unpack .../grub2-common_2.12-1ubuntu7_amd64.deb ...
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Unpacking grub2-common (2.12-1ubuntu7) ...
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Selecting previously unselected package grub-pc-bin.
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Preparing to unpack .../grub-pc-bin_2.12-1ubuntu7_amd64.deb ...
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Unpacking grub-pc-bin (2.12-1ubuntu7) ... 
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Selecting previously unselected package grub-pc.
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Preparing to unpack .../grub-pc_2.12-1ubuntu7_amd64.deb ...
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Unpacking grub-pc (2.12-1ubuntu7) ...
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Selecting previously unselected package grub-gfxpayload-lists.
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Preparing to unpack .../grub-gfxpayload-lists_0.7build2_amd64.deb ...
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Unpacking grub-gfxpayload-lists (0.7build2) ...
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Setting up grub2-common (2.12-1ubuntu7) ...
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Setting up grub-pc-bin (2.12-1ubuntu7) ...
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Setting up grub-gfxpayload-lists (0.7build2) ...
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Setting up grub-pc (2.12-1ubuntu7) ...
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]:  
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Creating config file /etc/default/grub with new version
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Processing triggers for install-info (7.1-3build2) ...
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: TIMED subp(['udevadm', 'settle']): 0.007  
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/usr/bin/ischroot'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/usr/bin/ischroot'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/sys'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/sys'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/run'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/run'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/proc'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/proc'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/dev', '/target/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/proc', '/target/proc'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/run', '/target/run'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/sys', '/target/sys'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/target/usr/bin/true', '/target/usr/bin/ischroot'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Checking if target_proc (/target/proc) is a mount
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: It is, so unshare will use --mount-proc=/target/proc
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--mount-proc=/target/proc', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'apt-get', 'clean'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: TIMED subp(['udevadm', 'settle']): 0.006
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/usr/bin/ischroot'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/usr/bin/ischroot'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/sys'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/sys'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/run'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/run'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/proc'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/proc'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks: SUCCESS: Installing packages on target system: ['grub-pc']
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks/installing-missing-packages: SUCCESS: installing missing packages
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: start: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks/configuring-iscsi-service: configuring iscsi service
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks/configuring-iscsi-service: SUCCESS: configuring iscsi service
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: start: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks/configuring-mdadm-service: configuring raid (mdadm) service
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks/configuring-mdadm-service: SUCCESS: configuring raid (mdadm) service
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: start: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks/configuring-nvme-over-tcp: configuring NVMe over TCP
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks/configuring-nvme-over-tcp: SUCCESS: configuring NVMe over TCP
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: start: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks/installing-kernel: installing kernel
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Checking if target_proc (/target/proc) is a mount
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: It's not, using normal behavior
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'lsb_release', '--all'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['dpkg', '--print-architecture'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Updating apt sources in /target
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/dev', '/target/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/proc', '/target/proc'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/run', '/target/run'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/sys', '/target/sys'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/target/usr/bin/true', '/target/usr/bin/ischroot'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Checking if target_proc (/target/proc) is a mount
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: It is, so unshare will use --mount-proc=/target/proc
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--mount-proc=/target/proc', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'apt-get', '--quiet', '--option=Acquire::Languages=none', 'update'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running in chroot, ignoring command 'start'
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Get:1 file:/cdrom noble InRelease
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Ign:1 file:/cdrom noble InRelease
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Get:2 file:/cdrom noble Release [1,072 B]
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Get:2 file:/cdrom noble Release [1,072 B]
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Reading package lists...
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: TIMED subp(['udevadm', 'settle']): 0.004
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/usr/bin/ischroot'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/usr/bin/ischroot'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/sys'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/sys'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/run'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/run'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/proc'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/proc'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/dev', '/target/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/proc', '/target/proc'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/run', '/target/run'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/sys', '/target/sys'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/target/usr/bin/true', '/target/usr/bin/ischroot'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Checking if target_proc (/target/proc) is a mount
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: It is, so unshare will use --mount-proc=/target/proc
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--mount-proc=/target/proc', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'apt-get', '--quiet', '--assume-yes', '--option=Dpkg::options::=--force-unsafe-io', '--option=Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold', 'install', '--download-only', 'linux-generic-hwe-24.04'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Reading package lists...
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Building dependency tree...
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Reading state information...
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: The following additional packages will be installed:
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: amd64-microcode bpfcc-tools bpftrace firmware-sof-signed hwdata ieee-data
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: intel-microcode iucode-tool libbpfcc libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libc6-dev
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: libclang-cpp18 libclang1-18 libcrypt-dev libllvm18 linux-firmware
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: linux-headers-6.8.0-31 linux-headers-6.8.0-31-generic
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04 linux-image-6.8.0-31-generic
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04 linux-libc-dev linux-modules-6.8.0-31-generic
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-31-generic linux-tools-6.8.0-31
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: linux-tools-6.8.0-31-generic linux-tools-common manpages-dev python3-bpfcc
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: python3-netaddr rpcsvc-proto thermald ubuntu-kernel-accessories
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Suggested packages:
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: glibc-doc fdutils linux-tools ipython3 python-netaddr-docs
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: The following NEW packages will be installed:
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: amd64-microcode bpfcc-tools bpftrace firmware-sof-signed hwdata ieee-data
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: intel-microcode iucode-tool libbpfcc libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libc6-dev
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: libclang-cpp18 libclang1-18 libcrypt-dev libllvm18 linux-firmware
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: linux-generic-hwe-24.04 linux-headers-6.8.0-31
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: linux-headers-6.8.0-31-generic linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: linux-image-6.8.0-31-generic linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04 linux-libc-dev
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: linux-modules-6.8.0-31-generic linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-31-generic
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: linux-tools-6.8.0-31 linux-tools-6.8.0-31-generic linux-tools-common
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: manpages-dev python3-bpfcc python3-netaddr rpcsvc-proto thermald
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: ubuntu-kernel-accessories
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: 0 upgraded, 35 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Need to get 0 B/735 MB of archives.
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: After this operation, 1,073 MB of additional disk space will be used.
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Err:20 file:/cdrom noble/main amd64 linux-modules-6.8.0-31-generic amd64 6.8.0-31.31
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Hash Sum mismatch
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Hashes of expected file:
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: - SHA512:7416ae03d47edcce7ec0973ca201df231a65c8b86cb40be5b7e2213c6b53dacdeff18f6f8068dd7f8d9526ab134cba6ea4f98e654f3f99801834cfef80dacf29
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: - SHA256:3f17f2c279257eb50e40da44390bdf8272c440ca078831c348773d1314b5c2fe
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: - Filesize:38348992 [weak]
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Hashes of received file:
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: - SHA512:fa6f910e64951f3c20b3b3e2bcd300ad0537c8aeefce8dfab8d37cba11064a5f9073acfae7bb55ef6afc030d4c630869c0eae517a6188dac03d3a0456647b048
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: - SHA256:65980681a3d11e2ff40a6cb68c9ae435833042ead8f12a9711715974f162ae48
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: - Filesize:38348992 [weak]
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Last modification reported: Sat, 20 Apr 2024 22:48:54 +0000
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: E: Failed to fetch file:/cdrom/pool/main/l/linux/linux-modules-6.8.0-31-generic_6.8.0-31.31_amd64.deb Hash Sum mismatch
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Hashes of expected file:
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: - SHA512:7416ae03d47edcce7ec0973ca201df231a65c8b86cb40be5b7e2213c6b53dacdeff18f6f8068dd7f8d9526ab134cba6ea4f98e654f3f99801834cfef80dacf29
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: - SHA256:3f17f2c279257eb50e40da44390bdf8272c440ca078831c348773d1314b5c2fe
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: - Filesize:38348992 [weak]
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Hashes of received file:
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: - SHA512:fa6f910e64951f3c20b3b3e2bcd300ad0537c8aeefce8dfab8d37cba11064a5f9073acfae7bb55ef6afc030d4c630869c0eae517a6188dac03d3a0456647b048
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: - SHA256:65980681a3d11e2ff40a6cb68c9ae435833042ead8f12a9711715974f162ae48
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: - Filesize:38348992 [weak]
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Last modification reported: Sat, 20 Apr 2024 22:48:54 +0000
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: E: Some files failed to download
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: TIMED subp(['udevadm', 'settle']): 0.008
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/usr/bin/ischroot'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/usr/bin/ischroot'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/sys'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/sys'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/run'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/run'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/proc'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/proc'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Running command ['umount', '/target/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks/installing-kernel: FAIL: installing kernel
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks: FAIL: curtin command curthooks
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Traceback (most recent call last):
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/main.py", line 202, in main
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: ret = args.func(args)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 2224, in curthooks
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: builtin_curthooks(cfg, target, state)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 2048, in builtin_curthooks
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: install_kernel(cfg, target)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 393, in install_kernel
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: install(kernel_package)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 369, in install
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: distro.install_packages([pkg], target=target, env=env)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/distro.py", line 473, in install_packages
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: return install_cmd('install', args=pkglist, opts=opts, target=target,
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/distro.py", line 255, in run_apt_command
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: cmd_rv = apt_install(mode, args, opts=opts, env=env, target=target,
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/distro.py", line 303, in apt_install
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: cmd_rv = inchroot.subp(cmd + dl_opts + packages, env=env,
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/util.py", line 843, in subp
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: return subp(*args, **kwargs)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/util.py", line 323, in subp
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: return _subp(*args, **kwargs)
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/util.py", line 172, in _subp
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: raise ProcessExecutionError(stdout=out, stderr=err,
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: curtin.util.ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Command: ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--mount-proc=/target/proc', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'apt-get', '--quiet', '--assume-yes', '--option=Dpkg::options::=--force-unsafe-io', '--option=Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold', 'install', '--download-only', 'linux-generic-hwe-24.04']
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Exit code: 100
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Reason: -
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Stdout: ''
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Stderr: ''
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Unexpected error while running command.
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Command: ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--mount-proc=/target/proc', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'apt-get', '--quiet', '--assume-yes', '--option=Dpkg::options::=--force-unsafe-io', '--option=Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold', 'install', '--download-only', 'linux-generic-hwe-24.04']
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Exit code: 100
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Reason: -
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Stdout: ''
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Stderr: ''
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]:
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_log.3824[10918]: Stderr: ''
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_event.3824[3824]: executing curtin install curthooks step  
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_event.3824[3824]: installing system
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_event.3824[3824]:  
May 08 21:48:55 ubuntu subiquity_event.3824[3824]: curtin command install


I see problems reading your source media; re-scan your pasted details & notice the "Hash Sum mismatch" errors... Did you verify your ISO prior to write to media? and then validate the ISO to media as being written correctly

Does this answer your question? Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?

@guiverc oh yes of course. sorry for details.
i want to install ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS and i downloaded the file from main website of ubuntu.

@guiverc bro do you wan to help me ? or not

As already stated... the message I see is "Err:20 file:/cdrom noble/main amd64 linux-modules-6.8.0-31-generic ... Hash Sum mismatch" where the CDROM is your install media; ie. your install media is bad... Either ISO was corrupted during download (did you verify it? as per documentation) OR your write of ISO to media was faulty...  Both those checks take seconds (ISO) or <two mins (media write verify) to check & will confirm which step caused the invalid media issue I see...  as per first comment.

@guiverc may it happened because of the app i used for boot on USB?
i used Betcher in windows.
and i tried to install and format hard drive for several times.
i don't know what should i do now.
can you give me a guide?
